# Unable to view content in DetailView Django

Tags: django

I am trying to view the content in my blog posts using django DetailView class but when I run the local server and click on the headline link in my blog post, while the url bar changes to read the correct post, the actual page stays the same, and so I can't view individual blog posts.
Here is the section of code were the problem lies.

```
#view.py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_list.html'

class PostDetailView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template = 'post_detail.html'

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('post/<int:pk>', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),   
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),]


#post_list.html
   {% for post in post_list %}
        <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2> 
            <p> {{ post.tagline }} </p>
```

Comment: You want Detail view and using Listview `PostDetailView(ListView)` Change it to DetailView

Comment: yep, correct.  must have happened when i was switching the names of models. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DetailView`

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
```